# RecyclerView don't fully expand inside ScrollView

Tags: android

I have following structure:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    <LinearLayout
       <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
          <LinearLayout 
              <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                 <LinearLayout(sime views below recycleview)
```

and in my Java code I have:

```
    myRecycleView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_rv);
    myRecycleView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

The problem is that my `Recyclerview` shows only one line.

**full xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rv_selections"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:baselineAligned="false"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <-- here some other views -->

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: show rest of xml

Comment: @TimCastelijns uploaded full simplified code

Comment: your RV can not have match_parent for height. Set it to wrap_content

Comment: @TimCastelijns Same result, just tested how it does with match_parent

Comment: then the issue is probably with your RV. Does it even have more than 1 elements inside?

Comment: :D it has more & that's really strange

Comment: check if RV item has smaller dimensions than the RV itself